# cpp run function that before it is declared?

Tags: c++

I'm new to CPP, and I want to know how to run a function that isn't in its scope. I'm used to doing such things in javascript, and I get an error CPP when I try to do that. What I mean is the below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int tic_h;
int tic_v;
void echo(string e_val){
   cout << e_val;
}
void c_mes(){
  echo("X|0|X\n");
  echo("-----\n");
  echo("X|0|X\n");
  echo("-----\n");
  echo("X|0|X\n");
  s_v();
}
void s_v(){
  echo("Please enter vertical coordinate: ");
  cin >> tic_v;
  if(tic_v<4&&tic_v>0){
    c_mes();
  }else{
    s_v();
  }
}
void s_h(){
  echo("Please enter horizontal coordinate: ");
  cin >> tic_h;
  if(tic_h<4&&tic_h>0){
    s_v();
  }else{
    s_h();
  }
}

int main(){
  s_h();
  return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

> error: 'sv' was not declared in this scope on line 16

How can I make it work?

Comment: Side note: Why are you abstracting `cout` behind `echo()`? In this program there is no point; just use, for example,  `cout << "X|0|X" << endl;`

Comment: I'm a web developer, so I just made the echo funtion(php) for convenience, because I'm used to that kind of syntax.'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should put a [function prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) before using the function, for the compiler to know what it is going to be.

Put

```
void s_v(); // prototype your functions, this is usually done in include files
```

Right after the `#include` line.

Comment: In C++, this is usually called a "declaration". The body of the function is provided by a "definition". The (single) definition of a function may follow its use, but a function must be declared before it's used. (There are exceptions for class methods).

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to [forward declare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) `dostuff`, as in the example below.

By doing this you pretty much tell the compiler that the function will be defined else where, but that you'd like to use it.

*Excuse the wording, but putting it the way I did is easily comprehensive by a novice programmer.*

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void dostuff (); // forward declaration

void test(int b){ 
    if(b<11&&b>0){
        cout << "Yay!";
    }   
    else{
        cout << "The number is not between 1 and 10.";
        dostuff();
    }   
}

void dostuff(){
    int numput;
    cout << "Please type a number between 1 and 10:";
    cin >> numput;
    test(numput);
}

int main(){
    dostuff();
}
```

*OP just edited the original snippet provided in his question (which the below is a modification off), I'll leave this post the way it is since it explains the situation quite well.*

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `void s_v();` before the `c_mes()` function. This is called a function prototype, and it lets the compiler know that that symbol exists and will be implemented later in the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int tic_h;
int tic_v;
void s_v();

void echo(string e_val) {
   cout << e_val;
}

void c_mes() {
    echo("X|0|X\n");
    echo("-----\n");
    echo("X|0|X\n");
    echo("-----\n");
    echo("X|0|X\n");
    s_v();
}

void s_v() {
    echo("Please enter vertical coordinate: ");
    cin >> tic_v;
    if (tic_v < 4 && tic_v > 0) {
        c_mes();
    } else {
        s_v();
    }
}

void s_h() {
    echo("Please enter horizontal coordinate: ");
    cin >> tic_h;
    if (tic_h < 4 && tic_h > 0) {
        s_v();
    } else {
        s_h();
    }
}

int main() {
  s_h();
  return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that if you ever change the signature for `s_v()` (that is, add arguments or change the return type), you will need to update the prototype as well.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `dostuff` somewhere before the `void test` definitionm e.g on line 3:

```
void dostuff();
```

This way you introduce the signature of `dostuff` function to your program before the function is defined.

In C++ unlike javascript and some other languages, the parser doesn't find all functions then compile the code.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
void dostuff();
```

just after the using namespace std; and it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the same error, you use a function before declare it (s_v()), for solve your error you only should create a prototype of s_v():

```
void s_v(); //at the start of your file
```

Answer (score 0):

write this

```
void c_mes(){
  echo("X|0|X\n");
  echo("-----\n");
  echo("X|0|X\n");
  echo("-----\n");
  echo("X|0|X\n");
  s_v();
}
```

after this

```
void s_h(){
  echo("Please enter horizontal coordinate: ");
  cin >> tic_h;
  if(tic_h<4&&tic_h>0){
    s_v();
  }else{
    s_h();
  }
}
```